# Android AVD Not detecting Google API as target

Tags: android, api, android-virtual-device

I have installed the Google API and created a Google API specific project in Eclipse. Although when i go to create a new AVD with the Target set to a Google API i only have the option for Android 4.2 - API Level 17. 
How can i make the Google API show so i can select it?

Comment: DO you have all the lower levels installed?

Answer (score 7):

Make sure to restart Eclipse after downloading Google APIs.

Answer (score 1):

I would double check that you have downloaded the Google API, and not just the Android API.  They will both have the same API number. Using the SDK Manager, you will see a variety of selections for downloads.  Make sure you have downloaded the "Google APIs" in addition to the "SDK Platform".

This is the behavior you would see if you don't have the Google portion downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Android SDK manager, then **download everything you needed** to create new AVD.

After finished downloading, you can create AVD with what you had just download.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to check your path to SDK location, it might be pointing to other SDK location where only Android 4.2-API Level 17 is installed.

You can do so by going to Window -> Preferences (in your eclipse), in Preferences goto Android, in Android you will see the SDK Location. Browse & change SDK Location to the SDK location where your Android SDK tools is installed. For Eg.: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk